# In Java, is there a way to add the last run of an element to an array in a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays

I have searched for an answer to this, and I can't seem to find a similar problem. I have spent the past few hours trying to fix this one problem, so I am asking for guidance. It is a method to RLE byte arrays.

I cannot seem to get the last run of elements in the array to output. Even if there is one element (ex. 15) it will output 0 0 not 1 15. I have been told to manually add the last run after the *for loop*.

Is there a way to add the last run in the *for loop*?

Input: 15 15 15 4 4 4 4 4 4

Outputs: 3 15 0 0

```
public static byte[] encodeRle(byte[] flatData)
{
    byte runLength = 1;
    byte indexTracker = 0;
    int runCount = countRuns(flatData);
    runCount *= 2;
    byte[] rleData = new byte[runCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < flatData.length - 1; i++)
    {
        if(flatData[i] != flatData[i+1] || runLength == 15)
        {
            rleData[indexTracker] = runLength;
            rleData[indexTracker + 1] = flatData[i];
            indexTracker += 2;
            runLength = 1;
        }
        else{
            runLength++;
        }
    }
    return rleData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a condition like below that will let your loop break in case you are at the last run of your input data.

```
public static byte[] encodeRle(byte[] flatData)
{
    byte runLength = 1;
    byte indexTracker = 0;
    int runCount = countRuns(flatData);
    runCount *= 2;
    byte[] rleData = new byte[runCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < flatData.length - 1; i++)
    {
        if(flatData[i] != flatData[i+1] || runLength == 15)
        {
            if(flagData[i+1] == flatData[flatData.length - 1]){
                rleData[indexTracker] = 0;
                rleData[indexTracker + 1] = 0;
                break;
            }

            rleData[indexTracker] = runLength;
            rleData[indexTracker + 1] = flatData[i];
            indexTracker += 2;
            runLength = 1;
        }
        else{
            runLength++;
        }
    }
    return rleData;
}
```

This will put 0 0 to your output array and will break the loop for last run.

Hope this will help you!